# Why is my NSURLConnection returning null?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm making an NSURLConnection to my server but `responseData` ends up being null in `connectionDidFinishLoading` and I can't figure out why.  Here's the code for the connection:

```
NSMutableData *responseData;

- (void)myFunction:(id)sender {

  NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com/";

  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

  [connection start];
}


// NSURLConnection Delegates
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  [responseData setLength:0];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  [responseData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

} // end connectionDidFinishLoading

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"Connection error: %@",[error description]);
}
```

Comment: Where is responseData initialized?

Comment: Yup!  That's it exactly, I copped it as soon as I posted the question and read it back.  Stick it in an answer and I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical!  Just as I finished posting the question the answer dawned on me.  I never initialized `responseData`.  So in `viewDidLoad` I added the line below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [super viewDidLoad];

  responseData = [NSMutableData data];

}
```

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, I'm used to initializing as responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init]; What does "[NSMutableData data]" do differently?

Comment: @Max: the class method returns an autoreleased object. Under ARC, they behave identically.

Answer (score 3):

responseData isn't initialized :)